# Index Formula - Google Form

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, google-forms

[Data from Google Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjDvR.png)
[Attendance Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhkRJ.png)

Hi,

I have attached two photos. I have readjusted the Google Form so that the data is easier to read but I am basically trying to index the results based on the name. While I am getting a result, it's not accurate, it seems to be offset or something. Just wondering if anyone can help please?

Thanks,
Shea

I tried using the OFFSET formula to bring it back a few columns but still not correct

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this in `Cell C6` of your attendance tab and see how it goes...

```
=IFNA(FILTER(FILTER(AB!$D:$Q,AB!$D$1:$Q$1=C$5),AB!$C:$C=$B$3,AB!$B:$B=$B6),"-")
```

Comment: That worked brilliantly thank you so much! Only thing is I can't get it to work dynamically now when i change the name. I played about with running IF instead of IFNA but it doesn't udpdate when I change the name and it takes data from the other forms "e.g. AS"

Comment: Hi Shea.. I just winged the formula based on screenshots. kinda tough to troubleshoot unless you can share a sample sheet replicating the design with demo data maybe.